# How to keep label smoothly centered in scrollbox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, tlabel, tscrollbox

I use a `TMemo` in `TScrollBox` to show some text, and a `TLabel` on top as a header info. Sometimes memo is wider than scroll box and of course `Horizontal scroll bar` can be used to scroll left and right to see text in memo. 
I want to have a label as a header always centered to scroll box visible area.  I can do this by setting `Label1.Left:= (Scrollbox1.Width div 2) - (Label1.Width div 2);` and it works but it kind of flickers, shakes when scrolling back and forth. Memo moves smoothly, label doesn't.

[image]

Here is unit:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  TScrollBox=Class(VCL.Forms.TScrollBox)
    procedure WMHScroll(var Message: TWMHScroll); message WM_HSCROLL;
  private
    FOnScrollHorz: TNotifyEvent;
  public
   Property OnScrollHorz:TNotifyEvent read FOnScrollHorz Write FonScrollHorz;
  End;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ScrollBox1: TScrollBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBox1Resize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure MyScrollHorz(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TScrollBox.WMHScroll(var Message: TWMHScroll);
begin
   inherited;
   if Assigned(FOnScrollHorz) then  FOnScrollHorz(Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.MyScrollHorz(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Label1.Left:= (Scrollbox1.Width div 2) - (Label1.Width div 2);
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBox1Resize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Left:= (Scrollbox1.Width div 2) - (Label1.Width div 2);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ScrollBox1.OnScrollHorz := MyScrollHorz;
end;

end.
```

and dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 212
  ClientWidth = 458
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ScrollBox1: TScrollBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 458
    Height = 212
    HorzScrollBar.Smooth = True
    HorzScrollBar.Tracking = True
    Align = alClient
    BiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
    DoubleBuffered = True
    ParentBiDiMode = False
    ParentDoubleBuffered = False
    TabOrder = 0
    OnResize = ScrollBox1Resize
    ExplicitHeight = 337
    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 192
      Top = 30
      Width = 69
      Height = 13
      BiDiMode = bdLeftToRight
      Caption = 'Details header'
      ParentBiDiMode = False
    end
    object Memo1: TMemo
      Left = 24
      Top = 70
      Width = 700
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Details...')
      TabOrder = 0
    end
  end
end
```

I tried using `DoubleBuffered` but doesn't help.

**Any suggestions how to make Label1 move without flickering/shaking, as smooth as Memo1 does when scrolling?**

---

**EDIT:**

The design will eventually be that I have 3 or scrollboxes on form and each one contain up to 3 memos with header. And scrolling needs to be by scrollbox as all memos in same scroll box need to be scrolled at the same time. That means I do not see how it would work with putting label on form or panel and then on form, outside scrollboxes:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2:**

The answers below do provide good solutions, but they do make necessary to place the `Labels`, that are centered, out of the `Scrollbox` and put on the `Form` itself. And then move either by `Scrollbox's` `scroll bars` or by `scroll bars` directly on `Form`. This does get desired affect, but it adds a little inconvenience with `Labels` not being part of `Scrollbox`, anymore.

Comment: you do not have to place the label onto scrollbox. use a panel as container, place a label on top onto panel and place a scrollbox as client component onto panel.

Comment: You are aware that you don't need the scrollbox at all, because the memo will allow scrolling using it's own scrollbars if you turn them on (using the TMemo.Scrollbars property, ironically). If you use that built-in scrolling, you don't need the scrollbox at all, and your label never needs to move.

Comment: @KenWhite, sddk: I can have up to 4 scrollboxes on form and up to 3 memos with headers in each scrollbox. So they need to be in grouped scrollboxes. I don't see how to put them on form/panel and to keep the needed design with scrolling relevant grouped information. See question edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-*" Memo moves smoothly, label doesn't.*"

That's because you're trying to prevent it from moving. Detach your `OnScrollHorz` handler and the label will move smoothly. But that's not what you want, it will not be centered to the form any more.

The problem is, during the `inherited` call (`WM_HSCROLL`), the label moves along with the memo. After the default handling, you relocate the label, hence the flicker.

You can expose an additional event handler that will fire before default scrolling (OnBeforeHorzScroll), and hide the label when it fires. While *smoothly centered*, it will cause a different kind of flicker where the label momentarily disappears. Still may not be satisfactory.

The solution is to use a control that is parented to the form, a sibling to the scroll box. You can't do that with a `TLabel` as it is a graphic control, but you can use `TStaticText`. The "structure pane" of the IDE may come handy if the *static* accidentally goes behind the scroll box at design time.

Comment: Aha, it does make sense now why it flickers. See picture of design in my Edit to the questions, which means I do not have many options to put headers on forms, as each scrollbox need to scroll all the grouped memo controls.

Comment: I think you can still use 'TStaticText's. Drop one on a scrollbox, use the structure pane to move it to the form, so that it's parent becomes the form. Calculate its position in OnResize of the form. Try one and I don't think there will be any complications.

Comment: It seems to be working OK like this, I'm just surprised why it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

Instead of ScrollBox put a ScrollBar on your form. Set its alignment to bottom (or set its size and position manually if you wish to have more columns or you can put each one in its own panel). Then set the size of your Memos and place Labels to the center of the Form. After setting the size of the Memos (probably dynamically via code) place this code:

```
ScrollBar1.Min:=0-Memo1.Left;
ScrollBar1.Max:=Memo1.Width-Form1.ClientWidth+Memo1.Left;
```

The last thing is to set the ScrollBar OnChange event:

```
procedure TForm1.ScrollBar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Left:=0-ScrollBar1.Position;
  Memo2.Left:=0-ScrollBar1.Position;
  ...
  MemoXY.Left:=0-ScrollBar1.Position;
end;
```

Your form should look something like this:

[image: Scrollable memos]

Done! You have a stable centered Labels and smoothly scrollable Memos.

**Edit:**

Here is a version with 3 columns each in his own Panel and also with vertical scrollbars:

[image: Vertical scroll]

And the whole source code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    Panel3: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Label5: TLabel;
    Label6: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    Memo3: TMemo;
    Memo4: TMemo;
    Memo5: TMemo;
    Memo6: TMemo;
    ScrollBar1: TScrollBar;
    ScrollBar2: TScrollBar;
    ScrollBar3: TScrollBar;
    ScrollBar4: TScrollBar;
    ScrollBar5: TScrollBar;
    ScrollBar6: TScrollBar;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBarHChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ScrollBarVChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var cycle: Integer;
begin
  //GENERATE YOUR COMPONENTS HERE

  //sets every components tag to its default top position
  //(you can do this in any other way for example using array)
  for cycle:=0 to Form1.ComponentCount-1 do
  begin
    if(Form1.Components[cycle] is TControl)then
      Form1.Components[cycle].Tag:=(Form1.Components[cycle] as TControl).Top
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //changes the panels sizes and positions
  Panel1.Width:=Form1.ClientWidth div 3;
  Panel2.Width:=Form1.ClientWidth div 3;
  Panel3.Width:=Form1.ClientWidth div 3;
  Panel2.Left:=Panel1.Width+1;
  Panel3.Left:=Panel1.Width+Panel2.Width+1;

  //if you dont want all scrollbars to reset on window resize, you need to handle the positioning of elements when window (and panels) size is changing
  ScrollBar1.Position:=ScrollBar1.Min;
  ScrollBar2.Position:=ScrollBar2.Min;
  ScrollBar3.Position:=ScrollBar3.Min;
  ScrollBar4.Position:=ScrollBar4.Min;
  ScrollBar5.Position:=ScrollBar5.Min;
  ScrollBar6.Position:=ScrollBar6.Min;

  //make these tests on the widest element of each panel (8 is just a margin so the memo has some space on the right)
  if((Memo1.Left+Memo1.Width)>(Panel1.ClientWidth-ScrollBar4.Width-8))then
  begin
    ScrollBar1.Enabled:=true;
    ScrollBar1.Max:=Memo1.Width-Panel1.ClientWidth+Memo1.Left+ScrollBar4.Width+8;
  end
  else
    ScrollBar1.Enabled:=false;

  if((Memo3.Left+Memo3.Width)>(Panel2.ClientWidth-ScrollBar5.Width-8))then
  begin
    ScrollBar2.Enabled:=true;
    ScrollBar2.Max:=Memo3.Width-Panel1.ClientWidth+Memo3.Left+ScrollBar5.Width+8;
  end
  else
  begin
    ScrollBar2.Position:=ScrollBar2.Min;
    ScrollBar2.Enabled:=false;
  end;

  if((Memo5.Left+Memo5.Width)>(Panel3.ClientWidth-ScrollBar6.Width-8))then
  begin
    ScrollBar3.Enabled:=true;
    ScrollBar3.Max:=Memo5.Width-Panel1.ClientWidth+Memo5.Left+ScrollBar6.Width+8;
  end
  else
    ScrollBar3.Enabled:=false;

  //make these tests on the bottom element of each panel (16 is just a margin so the memo has some space on the bottom)
  if((Memo2.Top+Memo2.Height)>(Panel1.ClientHeight-ScrollBar1.Height-16))then
  begin
    ScrollBar4.Enabled:=true;
    ScrollBar4.Max:=Memo2.Top+Memo2.Height-Panel1.ClientHeight+ScrollBar1.Height+16;
  end
  else
    ScrollBar4.Enabled:=false;

  if((Memo4.Top+Memo4.Height)>(Panel2.ClientHeight-ScrollBar2.Height-16))then
  begin
    ScrollBar5.Enabled:=true;
    ScrollBar5.Max:=Memo4.Top+Memo4.Height-Panel2.ClientHeight+ScrollBar2.Height+16;
  end
  else
    ScrollBar5.Enabled:=false;

  if((Memo6.Top+Memo6.Height)>(Panel3.ClientHeight-ScrollBar3.Height-16))then
  begin
    ScrollBar6.Enabled:=true;
    ScrollBar6.Max:=Memo6.Top+Memo6.Height-Panel3.ClientHeight+ScrollBar3.Height+16;
  end
  else
    ScrollBar6.Enabled:=false;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBarHChange(Sender: TObject);
var cycle: Integer;
begin
  for cycle:=0 to ((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    if(((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).Controls[cycle] is TMemo)then
      (((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).Controls[cycle] as TMemo).Left:=0-(Sender as TScrollBar).Position+8;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ScrollBarVChange(Sender: TObject);
var cycle: Integer;
begin
  for cycle:=0 to ((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).ControlCount-1 do
  begin
    if(not (((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).Controls[cycle] is TScrollBar))then
      (((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).Controls[cycle] as TControl).Top:=(((Sender as TScrollBar).Parent as TPanel).Controls[cycle] as TControl).Tag-(Sender as TScrollBar).Position;
  end;
end;

end.
```

And the .dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 473
  ClientWidth = 769
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnResize = FormResize
  DesignSize = (
    769
    473)
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 257
    Height = 473
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akBottom]
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsSingle
    TabOrder = 0
    object Label1: TLabel
      Left = 104
      Top = 16
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label1'
    end
    object Label2: TLabel
      Left = 104
      Top = 152
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label2'
    end
    object Memo1: TMemo
      Left = 8
      Top = 32
      Width = 497
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo1')
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object Memo2: TMemo
      Left = 8
      Top = 168
      Width = 497
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo2')
      TabOrder = 1
    end
    object ScrollBar1: TScrollBar
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 0
      Top = 452
      Width = 236
      Height = 17
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 17
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alBottom
      PageSize = 0
      TabOrder = 2
      OnChange = ScrollBarHChange
      ExplicitWidth = 253
    end
    object ScrollBar4: TScrollBar
      Left = 236
      Top = 0
      Width = 17
      Height = 452
      Align = alRight
      Enabled = False
      Kind = sbVertical
      PageSize = 0
      TabOrder = 3
      OnChange = ScrollBarVChange
      ExplicitTop = 248
      ExplicitHeight = 121
    end
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 256
    Top = 0
    Width = 257
    Height = 473
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akBottom]
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsSingle
    TabOrder = 1
    object Label3: TLabel
      Left = 104
      Top = 16
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label3'
    end
    object Label4: TLabel
      Left = 104
      Top = 152
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label4'
    end
    object Memo3: TMemo
      Left = 8
      Top = 32
      Width = 497
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo3')
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object Memo4: TMemo
      Left = 8
      Top = 168
      Width = 497
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo4')
      TabOrder = 1
    end
    object ScrollBar2: TScrollBar
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 0
      Top = 452
      Width = 236
      Height = 17
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 17
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alBottom
      PageSize = 0
      TabOrder = 2
      OnChange = ScrollBarHChange
      ExplicitWidth = 253
    end
    object ScrollBar5: TScrollBar
      Left = 236
      Top = 0
      Width = 17
      Height = 452
      Align = alRight
      Enabled = False
      Kind = sbVertical
      PageSize = 0
      TabOrder = 3
      OnChange = ScrollBarVChange
      ExplicitTop = 248
      ExplicitHeight = 121
    end
  end
  object Panel3: TPanel
    Left = 512
    Top = 0
    Width = 257
    Height = 473
    Anchors = [akLeft, akTop, akBottom]
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    BorderStyle = bsSingle
    TabOrder = 2
    object Label5: TLabel
      Left = 104
      Top = 16
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label5'
    end
    object Label6: TLabel
      Left = 104
      Top = 152
      Width = 31
      Height = 13
      Caption = 'Label6'
    end
    object Memo5: TMemo
      Left = 8
      Top = 32
      Width = 497
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo5')
      TabOrder = 0
    end
    object Memo6: TMemo
      Left = 8
      Top = 168
      Width = 497
      Height = 89
      Lines.Strings = (
        'Memo6')
      TabOrder = 1
    end
    object ScrollBar3: TScrollBar
      AlignWithMargins = True
      Left = 0
      Top = 452
      Width = 236
      Height = 17
      Margins.Left = 0
      Margins.Top = 0
      Margins.Right = 17
      Margins.Bottom = 0
      Align = alBottom
      PageSize = 0
      TabOrder = 2
      OnChange = ScrollBarHChange
      ExplicitWidth = 253
    end
    object ScrollBar6: TScrollBar
      Left = 236
      Top = 0
      Width = 17
      Height = 452
      Align = alRight
      Enabled = False
      Kind = sbVertical
      PageSize = 0
      TabOrder = 3
      OnChange = ScrollBarVChange
      ExplicitTop = 248
      ExplicitHeight = 121
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! How would you solve the issue when the Form's height is resized so that vertical scrollbars are needed? Labels would need to be 'scrolled' out of form, right?

Comment: I've edited the post so the second example has now a fully functional vertical scrollbars. Only downside is that both scrollbars resets themselves when user changes window size (this shouldn't be a big problem) and also there is a small square on the bottom right corner of each panel where you can see the components below (but you can easily hide this little square with a panel for example).

Comment: The ScrollBarChange events are universal so you can add as many different components to the panels as you wish and it'll still work. In a similar way you can find the component with the highest left+width and with the highest top+height in the FormResize and make that universal too. Then you just need to create som components and it'll work everytime.

If you want to use it and need help with making the FormResize event universal, I can help with that too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use two scroll boxes.

You use one for vertical scrolling. On it you place your label and your second scroll box with memo on it.

This second scroll box will then be used for horizontal scrolling when needed.

Or perhaps even a better solution would be to replace TMemo with some other control like TRichEdit which has its own scrollbars implemented. So you have only one scroll box like now and TRichEdit Will take care of its own scrolling when the text is to wide.

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of Srollbox to group multiple TMemo (or TRichEdit) together in a combined view, to use single scroll bar to scroll content into view. Right?

Comment: Sorry I haven't noticed that you want to scroll all three of your memos at the same time. This complicates things a bit. For such scenario @jano152 answer is probably the best one.